# Post request with sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-7

I am new to Ruby on Rails and Sidekiq. I want to set this post request to be done in Sidekiq queue and I don't know how to send it to the perform method

**My controller Class code**

```
def create
    BaseWorkerJob.perform_async
end

private

  def book_params
    params.require(:book).permit(:title,:comment)
  end

  def author_params
    params.require(:author).permit(:first_name,:last_name,:age)
  end
```

I tried to make the params methods public but no change

**My BaseWorkerJob class code**

```
class BaseWorkerJob
  include Sidekiq::Job
  sidekiq_options retry:0
  require './app/controllers/api/v1/books_controller.rb'
  include Api::V1

  def perform
    author=
    Author.find_or_create_by(
    first_name:author_params[:first_name],
    last_name:author_params[:last_name],age:author_params[:age])
    book = Book.new(BooksController.book_params.merge(author_id: author.id))
    book.save
  end
end
```

**SideKiq Error**

[image: error from SideKiq docker container]

ruby 3.1.2 
Rails 7.0.4

Answer (score 0):

`author_params` is a `private` method and you are trying to access it outside of the controller.

you can pass `author_params` to `perform` the method.
your controller code should be:

```
def create
    BaseWorkerJob.perform_async(author_params)
end

private

  def book_params
    params.require(:book).permit(:title,:comment)
  end

  def author_params
    params.require(:author).permit(:first_name,:last_name,:age)
  end
```

And BaseWorkerJob class will have below:

```
class BaseWorkerJob
  include Sidekiq::Job
  sidekiq_options retry:0
  require './app/controllers/api/v1/books_controller.rb'
  include Api::V1

  def perform(author_params)
    author=Author.find_or_create_by(
      first_name:author_params[:first_name],
      last_name:author_params[:last_name],
      age:author_params[:age])
    book = Book.new(BooksController.book_params.merge(author_id: author.id))
    book.save
  end
```

I hope this will help you.